# Change Icon Button from Another JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans

I just want to do when you press the button "VACATE" change icon button something like this:

```
 public void changeIcon(){

    ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon("01.png");
    btnUno.setIcon(icono);
```

this method effectively changes the image, but this one does not:

```
public void changeVacant(){

    ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon("btnUno.png");
    btnUno.setIcon(icono);
```

The first method call when pressed to buy, the other method is another JFrame and press vacate.

Answer (score 0):

In the first function you called setIcon() which sets the Icon you see most of the time. In the second you called setPressedIcon() which sets the icon you will only see when you are holding that button down.

Comment: I have same problem with setIcon()

Comment: Can you post enough code for me to reproduce the problem?

Comment: i have 2 JFrames, in the "Father" Frame i have a button, when button was pressed the method changeIcon is called, in the "Son" Frame i have another button, when button was pressed the method changeVacant is called, my problem is that the changeVacant method does not change the picture